# mac os x の emacs で、 GPG error: "no usable configuration"

Tags: macos, emacs

brew cask で Emacs.app をインストールしました。バージョンは 25.3 です。

以下の設定のみを記述した状態で emacs を初期化すると、`list-packages` の際に、 gpg のエラーが発生している様子で、 gnu の package を取得できません。

#### init.el

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-check-signature t)
(package-initialize)
```

#### emacs が `list-packages` 時に `*Messages*` で伝えるエラー内容

```
Cannot import default keyring: ("no usable configuration" OpenPGP)
Package refresh done
error in process filter: epg-context--make: GPG error: "no usable configuration", OpenPGP
error in process filter: GPG error: "no usable configuration", OpenPGP
```

`package-check-signature` を nil に設定すれば、通るのかもしれませんが、確か、 emacs の packages のダウンロードはあまりセキュアでなかったと記憶していて、なので signature のチェックは強制したいと考えています。

### 質問

- package-check-signature を t にした状態で、 gnu のパッケージを取得できるようになりたいです。どうやったらこれを実現できますでしょうか。

Comment: emacs.stackexchange にもマルチポストしています。 https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36889/9371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パッケージを検証するためのプログラム (`gpg`) がインストールされているか確認してください。

もしなければ、https://gnupg.org/download/ からダウンロードするか `brew install gnupg` でインストールしてください。

蛇足ですが、変数`package-check-signature`を`t` (すべて検証する) に設定すると、[MELPA](https://melpa.org/)などのパッケージに署名のないサイトではエラーが発生します。`gpg`プログラムが入っていれば`'allow-unsigned` (未署名を許容する) がデフォルト設定になっているはずです。こちらを選択したほうが無難かもしれません。